# Load pixmap from buffer in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have the following details about an image

```
int nBufSize ;   //contains the buffer size
void* lpBmpBuf;   //The pointer to the first byte of the bitmap buffer
```

How can I obtain a QPixmap from this ?

Here is what I am doing so far

```
QByteArray b((char*)lpBmpBuf,nBufSize);
bool t = pix.loadFromData(b,  0, Qt::AutoColor);
```

However t is false in this case. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What kind of data does lpBmpBuf contain? A `.bmp` file contents?

Comment: Yes it contains a bmp file

Answer (score 4):

Copy the bitmap buffer into a byte array as you also have the length, then:

```
QPixmap::loadFromData(&data, 0, Qt::AutoColor);
```

data is the `QByteArray` in my example.

Also if you know the extension/type of the file you can specify it in the 2nd argument:

```
loadFromData(&data, "BMP");
```

Comment: can you try with unsigned char instead of char?